# Why does Function extend Record in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, static-typing

```
const fn = () => null
type Answer = typeof fn extends Record<string, any> ? true : false
```

The snippet above produces `Answer` to be of type `true`, indicating that a function is considered a subtype of `Record`. Why?

How can I make my types more strict so that functions are not its subtype?

Comment: "How can I make my types more strict"...  which types, exactly?  Probably whatever you have can be made more strict than `Record<string, any>`

Comment: I just want things that are objects, but are not callable. It's for a very global validator function and checking if something is an "object" (a record) is done in order to recursively traverse the tree of validators. I guess the question is "how to type a Record which is not a function?". I tried `Exclude<Record<string, any>, Function>` but that still allows a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, according to your comment, you want something like "an object which is not a function". TypeScript doesn't currently have [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196), so there's no concise way to express "not a function".  Depending on your use case, you might just want to shrug and move on.

Or, you might try to force TypeScript to bend to your will with a workaround.

---

The simplest workaround is to find some property that functions always have and declare that your type has an incompatible optional property of the same name.  For example:

```
type NoCall = { call?: number | string | boolean | null | undefined, [k: string]: any };
const okay: NoCall = { a: 4 }; // okay
const err: NoCall = () => 2; // error
```

A drawback is that you'd lose the ability to validate some legitimate non-functions (in the above case, `{call: ()=>0}` is not a function but would fail to validate as a `NoCall`).  But maybe some false positives are okay for your use case?

Anyway, reasonable choices according to the standard library [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L272-L304) for property names to check are `apply`, `call`, `bind`, `arguments`, and `caller`.

---

If you don't like giving up one of those names, you could optionally use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to add a phantom property to the `Function` interface:

```
declare global {
  interface Function {
    '*FunctionsHaveThis*': true
  }
}
type ObjNotFunction = { '*FunctionsHaveThis*'?: never, [k: string]: any };
const okay: ObjNotFunction = { a: 4 }; // okay
const err: ObjNotFunction = () => 2; // error
```

which makes property name collisions less likely but pollutes the global namespace and makes this workaround considerably less simple.

---

Another workaround is to use a [trick](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671) with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) which prevent a function from being passed as a parameter to another function:

```
function noFunctionsPlease<T extends object>(t: T & (T extends Function ? never : T)) {
  // do something with t
}
noFunctionsPlease({ a: 4 }); // okay
noFunctionsPlease(() => 2); // error
```

The type of `t` is more or less exactly saying "an object that isn't a function", but it can only be expressed as a function argument.

---

Hope one of those helps you or gives you an idea about how (or whether) to proceed.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I like the `call` one. Already did a workaround by switching around conditions so I ask for everything except the object and then simple leave that as the "else" case... Time to refactor that again \m/

Answer (score 3):

`Record<string, any>` indicates any object that has any string key and any value. All functions are objects, and they have some properties ( we can even index into the object `fn['call']`). By these definitions, and since type relations in Typescript are based on structure, `typeof fn` does extend `Record<string, any>`